# How to treat html document as string

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

I am displaying `htm` files in my app with a web view and I want to be able to do some analysis on the files in the app. For example, if the file was of a football schedule from 2009, I would want to count the number of "w"s in the file in order to have a total number of wins for that season. Any ideas?
and i mean "htm" files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be help full to you

you can get the html string from the webview .

```
 NSString *currentURL = [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by parsing the html by using NSScanner class

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining that bit of code a little for me? I'm a little new to objective-c